# Receiving with MPI_Type_vector in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a a statically allocated 2D array NxN, and I want to send the `i`th column (with `i = 0 ... N-1`).

I write:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int myrank, nprocs;
    int i,j;

    int matrix[N][N]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};
    int col[N];

    ...

    // Define type "column"
    MPI_Datatype column;
    MPI_Type_vector(N,1,N,MPI_INT,&column);
    MPI_Type_commit(&column);

    if(myrank==0){
        j=0;
        MPI_Send(&matrix[0][j],1,column,1,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    if(myrank==1){
        // **** FIRST MODE: Don't use "column" type *****
        MPI_Recv(col,N,MPI_INT,0,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&info);

        // **** SECOND MODE: Use "column" type *****
        // MPI_Recv(col,1,column_INT,0,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&info);

        printf("\nColumn: ");
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            printf("\n %d",col[j]);
    }

    MPI_Type_free(&column);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the first mode return correctly:

```
1 5 9 13
```

And the second return incorrectly?

```
1  -2  1980804601  1980804675
```

Comment: please accept the answer by Jonathan Dursi : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13523051/281545

Answer (score 6):

The MPI data type describes both the layout of the data and how much of it there is.   So for instance, a count of 1 of your column types describes N ints, but so would a count of N `MPI_INT`s.   The difference is that your column type (correctly) describes jumping around in an array of size NxN to extract a column.   Sending using that type extracts the N ints, and bundles them into a message.

So when you send, you send one of the column types to send the particular N ints which form a column in your array.  But when it's time to receive, while you still want to be receive N ints, but you're receiving it into a contiguous 1d array of integers (your `col[]` array), so you just want to receive N `MPI_INT`s.   If you receive into a column data type, you'll still receive N ints, but they will be put into memory spaced N ints apart (indeed, if N is large enough you'll get a segfault, as you're writing well outside the bounds of your col array).  This is why when you received with a column type, only the first number was correct; the rest were garbage because the rest of the array remains uninitialized.  Your second piece of data, `5`, will have been written just past the end of your col array.

Comment: Thank you Jonhatan! Now, I try to implement some exercises about this argument.